# Converting Every Child Tags in to a Single Column with multiple Delimiters (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery

This is my XML

```
<plan>
  <prescription>
    <name>ABC</name>
    <frequency>Daily</frequency>
    <dailyfrequency>
       <morning>2</morning>
       <afternoon></afternoon>
       <night>1</night>
    </dailyfrequency>
  </prescription>
  <prescription>
    <name>EDF</name>
    <frequency>Daily</frequency>
    <dailyfrequency>
      <morning>5</morning>
      <afternoon>5</afternoon>
      <evening>4</evening>
      <night>1</night>
   </dailyfrequency>
   <dayfrequency></dayfrequency>
  </prescription>
  <prescription>
    <name>YTER</name>
    <frequency>Weekly</frequency>
    <dailyfrequency>
      <morning>5</morning>
      <afternoon>5</afternoon>
      <evening>4</evening>
      <night>1</night>
    </dailyfrequency>
    <dayfrequency>Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday</dayfrequency>
  </prescription>
</plan>
```

I queried like the below using the Cross Join

```
PLAN=    STUFF(XMLData.query('for $a in 
    (*:ClinicalDocuments/Visits/Visit/prescriptions/prescription) 

return <a>{concat("$", $a)}</a>').value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
```

But i result will display like this

```
**PLAN**
ABCDaily21$EDFDaily5541$YTERWeekly5541Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday
```

But i really want to be like the below(Assume ***$-Column delimiter for every tag inside the prescription*** ,***!-Column Delimiter for Each Prescription itself***)

```
**PLAN**
ABC$Daily$2$0$0$1$0!EDF$Daily$5$5$4$1$0!YTER$Weekly$5$5$4$1$Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday
```

Please anyone helps me here !

(Note:Some child tags mayn't be present i.e, indicates it dosen't have values)

Thanks Very much in advance,**Jayendran**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following could be what you need, but I do not really know, how you want to handle *elements not present*. In your sample you placed `0` instead, but this is not a missing value but a dedicated default. This would need some knowlegde about the underlying data type...

Try this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<plan>
  <prescription>
    <name>ABC</name>
    <frequency>Daily</frequency>
    <dailyfrequency>
       <morning>2</morning>
       <afternoon></afternoon>
       <night>1</night>
    </dailyfrequency>
  </prescription>
  <prescription>
    <name>EDF</name>
    <frequency>Daily</frequency>
    <dailyfrequency>
      <morning>5</morning>
      <afternoon>5</afternoon>
      <evening>4</evening>
      <night>1</night>
   </dailyfrequency>
   <dayfrequency></dayfrequency>
  </prescription>
  <prescription>
    <name>YTER</name>
    <frequency>Weekly</frequency>
    <dailyfrequency>
      <morning>5</morning>
      <afternoon>5</afternoon>
      <evening>4</evening>
      <night>1</night>
    </dailyfrequency>
    <dayfrequency>Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday</dayfrequency>
  </prescription>
</plan>';
```

### update: added a predicate to exclude `<dailyfrequence>`

```
SELECT STUFF(
(
    SELECT '!' + STUFF(p.query(N'for $n in .//*[local-name()!="dailyfrequency"]
                           return <a>{concat("$",($n/text())[1])}</a>'
                        ).value(N'.',N'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'')
    FROM @xml.nodes(N'/plan/prescription') AS A(p)
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value(N'.',N'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'')
```

The result

```
ABC$Daily$2$$1!EDF$Daily$5$5$4$1$!YTER$Weekly$5$5$4$1$Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday
```

Missing values are indicated by *no value*.

Comment: thanks for our answer it works fine.When i changed my xml a little bit and while trying our answer it behaves differently.I have posted another Question with all the related details,could you please look through that.Thanks

Comment: The question which i posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44481065/converting-every-child-tags-in-to-a-single-column-with-multiple-delimiters-sql