# Converting Every Child Tags in to a Single Column with multiple Delimiters -SQL Server (2)

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery

```
declare @xml xml='<plan>
    <prescriptions id="1">
        <prescription>
            <name>ABC</name>
            <frequency>Daily</frequency>
            <dailyfrequency>
               <morning>2</morning>
               <afternoon></afternoon>
               <night>1</night>
            </dailyfrequency>
            <dayfrequency></dayfrequency>
        </prescription>
        <prescription>
            <name>EDF</name>
            <frequency>Daily</frequency>
            <dailyfrequency>
              <morning>5</morning>
              <afternoon>5</afternoon>
              <night>1</night>
           </dailyfrequency>
           <dayfrequency></dayfrequency>
        </prescription>
        <prescription>
            <name>YTER</name>
            <frequency>Weekly</frequency>
            <dailyfrequency>
              <morning>5</morning>
              <afternoon>5</afternoon>
              <night>1</night>
            </dailyfrequency>
            <dayfrequency>Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday</dayfrequency>
        </prescription>
    </prescriptions>
    <prescriptions id="2">
        <prescription>
            <name>YTRE</name>
            <frequency>Daily</frequency>
            <dailyfrequency>
               <morning>2</morning>
               <afternoon></afternoon>
               <night>1</night>
            </dailyfrequency>
            <dayfrequency></dayfrequency>
          </prescription>
    </prescriptions>
</plan>'
```

We can query like below to segregate each elements with multiple delimiter to be resulted in same column.

```
SELECT STUFF(
(
    SELECT '!' + STUFF(p.query(N'for $n in .//*[local-name()!="dailyfrequency"]
                           return <a>{concat("$",($n/text())[1])}</a>'
                        ).value(N'.',N'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'')
    FROM @xml.nodes(N'/plan/prescriptions/prescription') AS A(p)
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value(N'.',N'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'')
```

**Result:**

```
ABC$Daily$2$$1$!EDF$Daily$5$5$1$!YTER$Weekly$5$5$1$Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday!YTRE$Daily$2$$1$
```

But the problem here is this will combine all the tags under a single column.When we look the xml it has 2 major division Prescription id=1 and prescritpion id=2.So our final result will be like this

**Result:**

```
ABC$Daily$2$$1$!EDF$Daily$5$5$1$!YTER$Weekly$5$5$1$Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday
YTRE$Daily$2$$1$
```

I think we have to Shred the Xml for each <**Prescriptions**> then have to calculate this

Could someone please here to solve this

Thanks in advance,Jayendran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query like this:

```
SELECT STUFF(
(
    SELECT '!' + STUFF(p.query(N'for $n in .//*[local-name()!="dailyfrequency"]
                           return <a>{concat("$",($n/text())[1])}</a>'
                        ).value(N'.',N'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'')
    FROM p.nodes(N'prescription') AS A(p)
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value(N'.',N'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'')
FROM @xml.nodes(N'/plan/prescriptions') AS A(p);
```

First we create a derived table for the different prescriptions, Secondly we use the former code for each prescription separately.

Comment: I Struct into more complexity XML,which makes me to querying difficult.Could you please help me here to solve 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44514886/converting-every-child-tags-in-to-a-single-column-with-multiple-delimiters-sql