# Converting Every Child Tags in to a Single Column with multiple Delimiters -SQL Server (3)

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery

**My xml:**

```
declare @x xml='<Detail>
    <ROll ID="1">
         <Exams>
                <Examdetails date="2017-04-02 13:30:00">
                  <Exam name="ECO" Total="100">150</Exam>
                  <Exam name="BIO" Total="150">50</Exam>
                  <Exam name="MATH" Total="200">28</Exam>
                </Examdetails>

                <Examdetails date="2017-04-02 14:30:00">
                  <Exam name="ENGLISH" Total="100">150</Exam>
                  <Exam name="BIO" Total="200">50</Exam>
                  <Exam name="ZIO" Total="250">28</Exam>
                </Examdetails>
         </Exams>
    </ROll> 
    <ROll ID="2">
         <Exams>
                <Examdetails date="2017-05-02 13:30:00">
                  <Exam name="HIS" Total="100">150</Exam>
                  <Exam name="BIO" Total="200">50</Exam>
                  <Exam name="THI" Total="200">89</Exam>
                </Examdetails>
         </Exams>
    </ROll>
</Detail>'
```

I want to Segregate my xml based on ROLL ID's while i tried with the below query referred from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44481065/converting-every-child-tags-in-to-a-single-column-with-multiple-delimiters-sql)

```
SELECT STUFF(
(
    SELECT '!' + STUFF(p.query(N'for $n in .//*
                           return <a>{concat("$",($n/text())[1])}</a>'
                        ).value(N'.',N'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'')
    FROM p.nodes(N'Exams') AS A(p)
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value(N'.',N'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'')
FROM @x.nodes(N'Detail/ROll') AS A(p);
```

I get the result as

[image]

But i want to query it back as

```
2017-04-02 13:30:00$ECO$100$150!2017-04-02 13:30:00$BIO$150$50!2017-04-02 13:30:00$MATH$200$28!2017-04-02 14:30:00$ENGLISH$100$150!2017-04-02 14:30:00$BIO$200$50!2017-04-02 14:30:00$ZIO$250$28
2017-05-02 13:30:00$HIS$100$150!2017-05-02 13:30:00$BIO$200$50!2017-05-02 13:30:00$THI$200$89
```

Kindly help me solve this complexity

Thanks in advance ,Jayendran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I'd leave the generical path and build it up like this:

```
SELECT r.value(N'@ID',N'int') AS ROll_ID
,STUFF((
    SELECT 
           (
           SELECT '!'+ed.value(N'@date',N'nvarchar(max)')
                 +'$' + e.value(N'@name','nvarchar(max)')
                 +'$' + e.value(N'@Total','nvarchar(max)')
                 +'$' + e.value(N'text()[1]','nvarchar(max)')
           FROM ed.nodes(N'Exam') AS D(e)
           FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
           ).value(N'text()[1]','nvarchar(max)')  
    FROM ex.nodes(N'Examdetails') AS C(ed)
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
).value(N'text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'')
FROM @x.nodes(N'/Detail/ROll') AS A(r)
CROSS APPLY r.nodes(N'Exams') AS B(ex);
```

Main issues why a generic solution might not work:

- it is difficult to mix attributes and element's `text()` generically
- (**important!**) the attributes order is not guaranteed! Attribute values might appear not in order expected...